# How to use thread in my tcpserver program to communicate between two client through server?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp

```
    int main()
    {
int sock, connected, bytes_recieved , true = 1;
char send_data [1024] , recv_data[1024];
pid_t pid;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;
int sin_size;

if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
{
    perror("Socket");
    exit(1);
}

if (setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&true,sizeof(int)) == -1)   
{
    perror("Setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);

if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
{
    perror("Unable to bind");
    exit(1);
}

if (listen(sock, 5) == -1)
{
    perror("Listen");
    exit(1);
}

printf("\nTCPServer Waiting for client on port 5000\n");
fflush(stdout);

while(1)
{
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
    printf("\n I got a connection from (%s , %d)\n",    inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
                //fork this process into a child and parent
            pid = fork();

    //Check the return value given by fork(), if negative then error,
    //if 0 then it is the child.
            if ( pid == -1)
    {
                perror("fork()");
            }
    //loop until client closes
    if (pid == 0)
    {
                /*Child Process*/

                close(sock);

        while(1)
        {
            printf("\n SEND (q or Q to quit) : \n");
            gets(send_data);

            if (strcmp(send_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(send_data , "Q") == 0)   
            {
                send(connected, send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
                close(connected);
                break;
            }

            else

                send(connected, send_data,strlen(send_data), 0);
            bytes_recieved = recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
            recv_data[bytes_recieved] = '\0';

            if (strcmp(recv_data , "q") == 0 || strcmp(recv_data , "Q") == 0)   
            {
                close(connected);
                break;
            }
            else

            printf("\n RECIEVED DATA = from(%s,%d)\ndata=%s\n" ,inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port), recv_data);

            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }
}
close(sock);
return 0;}
```

i want to use the thread for client to client communication.
but how to create the thread and where i have to create the thread for multi client communication.
i have also use fork for accessing the multiple client.
i want to make the multiple client chat program in c using tcp/ip concept
thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the client thread when `accept()` returns, passing client information to the thread function. From your code, it looks like you've managed to do it (I haven't really compiled and checked, but it looks OK). So perhaps you could add more information about what's wrong with your code.

Comment: i want multiple client to client communication through server...
and i think it may be possible to using thread...

Comment: it's even possible without using `select()`. do you want the server to act as a middle layer (e.g. every communication must go through the server first) or directly client to client?

Comment: i have seen that for handling multiple client we have to use the select function...but how to work is properly that i don't know....

Comment: yes, i want server as a middle layer...
i think it's not possible without using select() function..

Comment: Actually i want send a message to a another client from different client through sever...so what change i have to do in this program...

Comment: define the protocol first, say `SEND <to> <msg>`. your client should send the message in this protocol format, which your server must parse. i.e. checking whether client named <to> exists or not, and send <msg> to it if exists. otherwise, send error code which your client should determine what it means (the code and meaning is also part of the protocol, so once again, define it). your client shouldn't be made console app as it won't be able to see messages directly (the input prompt would block) unless you know how to make input with timeout or something similar.